# Control click through transparency c#

Tags: c#, wpf, transparent

I am making a form that is transparent. However, I would like to sometimes be able to click "through" the form. What I mean is that I need to be able to control whether clicks go through the form or not. I am using Windows 8, which I heard makes a difference in this case as well. How can I do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Refining my question: I am making a form which is transparent and maximized. When a user clicks, the form catches the click then moves it from the previous location which was clicked, and clicks "through" the form at the new location. I've got most of it working in C# and WPF, but I cannot simulate clicks "through" the form. How would I do this?

Comment: You cannot control this.  The parts that are transparent are also click-through.

Comment: I assume you are using Winforms, I suggest switching to WPF as this handles this out of the box

Comment: @sa_ddam213, I changed it to use WPF, but was unable to find how WPF handles it out of the box. I refined my question, can you answer it?